# Difference between Spring boot 2.5.0 generated *jar and *-plain.jar?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I upgraded my spring boot app to 2.5.0, then is app.jar and app-plain.jar is created by gradle.

I would like to the difference between these jars.

thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`app.jar` is the archive produced by the `bootJar` task. This is a Spring Boot fat jar that contains all of the module's dependencies as well as its classes and resources. It can be run using `java -jar`.

`app-plain.jar` is the archive produced by the `jar` task. This is a plain or standard jar file that contains only the module's classes and resources.

You can learn a bit more about this in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.1/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.and-plain-archives) for Spring Boot's Gradle plugin.